# "Error deleting file: Permission denied" with remove in C++

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

When I compile and run my C++ program that deletes a file called example.txt (below)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  if( remove( "example.txt" ) != 0 )
    perror( "Error deleting file" );
  else
    puts( "File successfully deleted" );
  return 0;
}
```

It comes out like this...

```
cd c:\Users\Mark\Desktop  
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop>app.exe  
Error deleting file: Permission denied
```

I lifted all restrictions on the file and there is full access to anyone (that should  include my program).

Any solutions?

**EDIT**

When I type in `del example.txt` on command prompt it works.

Weird...

Comment: Well, I have a shortcut that opens a batch file that runs the program So yes...

Comment: What's the error message? perror should give you an error string. There's nothing right after your "it comes out like this" line. Can you delete that file in a command line?

Comment: What happens when instead of `app.exe` you type `del example.txt` in the command prompt?

Comment: This is not a C++ problem it is an OS problem.

Comment: Mark, SB is asking if some other program has opened / locked example.txt ... say if you have notepad open to (re-)create that file.

Comment: No nothing open to edit it with, this is a confusing problem :P

Comment: You could download `procmon` from the Sysinternals tool suite to see what really happens. Then you can compare the actions of your program with those from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) takes the path as a parameter. So we need to specify the entire path as a parameter for `remove` function.

eg: `remove("home/xxx/example.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have permission to change files in this place from your visual studio code.

I had this problem and I changed the file location and than I had no more problem.