# remove("<filename>"); Error removeing file: Permission denied

Tags: c, permission-denied, delete-file

I have a problem in this little codepart. It doesn't delete the file called `adatok.txt`. In this program I have many information in a file stored in the form of `DIAK`(my structure), and all of this information has a number(`diak.sorszam`). When I want to delete one of my information I enter the number of the information witch is stored in the `torol`, after that I store my useful information in the file called `sadatok.txt` and after closing these two files I want to delete `adatok.txt`, and rename `sadatok.txt` to `adatok.txt`, but for some reasons on the screen appears SucsessfullError deleting file: Permission denied...

```
...
    system("cls");
    int torol,stat=0;
    printf("\n\n\tDeleting number:");
    scanf("%d",&torol);
    FILE *fp, *sfp;
    fp = fopen("adatok.txt","rb");
    sfp = fopen("sadatok.txt","ab");
    DIAK diak;
    while(fread(&diak,sizeof(DIAK),1,fp)!=0){
        if(diak.sorszam==torol){
            stat=1;
        }else{
            fwrite(&diak,sizeof(DIAK),1,sfp);
        }
   }
   fclose(sfp);
   fclose(fp);
   system("cls");
   if(stat==1){
        printf("\n\n\tSucsessfull");
        if(remove("adatok.txt")!=0){
            perror("Error deleting file");
        }else{
            perror("File successfully deleted");
        }
        rename("sadatok.txt","adatok.txt");
   }else{
        printf("\n\n\tUnsucsessfull");
        if(remove("sadatok.txt")!=0){
            perror("Error deleting file");
        }else{
            perror("File successfully deleted");
        }   
   }
   printf("\n\tPress a buton");
   getch();
   ...
```

Comment: Don't use `perror()` when the function call was successful.

Comment: On which operating system, and with which file system? Please edit your question to improve it!

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of: ["Error deleting file: Permission denied" with remove in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3549900/3194340)

You should add a `\n` to improve your output traces:

```
printf("\n\n\tSucsessfull\n");
```

Then:

- Try to give the absolute path of the file to `remove()`
- Check the permissions of your running program

Answer (score 0):

You may not have permission to delete the file. Change the permission of the file and directory in which you are running the program to `rwx` by using `chmod`

Comment: To remove a file on Linux or Posix, you generally need `rwx` permission in its directory (but directories with sticky bit set are an exception)